# How to create a Jump list for any program?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, shortcuts, right-click, jumplist

To explain further, check this image first that show the context menu when right-clicking an app in the taskbar:

[image]

You can see a list of tasks that will be called immediately after launching the app. 
Can I create a shortcut that when clicked it acts as if you clicked a specific task?

Comment: @somebadhat Thanks for the hint. Although it was useful to know how to launch Snip with command line, that wasn't my question. I want to know how to create a Jump list for any program. I attached a new screenshot to explain more.

Comment: You said nothing about a jump list. You asked "How can I create a shortcut to a specific task of Windows 10 app"? To create a shortcut with arguments you have to know what arguments the command will take, hence the google search "snip command line". And you don't mean snip do you? You mean Snip & Sketch. It is a toss-up whether you are more likely to get help it you limit your inquiry to snip and sketch or go bttw for "any".

Comment: @somebadhat I assumed the rest of the question explains further. I mentioned that I need a shortcut to a specific task (I knew later it is called Jump list) and provided a picture of specific example tasks. 
My bad, I will try to make it more clear.

Comment: I am confused now.  Do you "want to know how to create a jump list for any program" or do you want to know how to create a windows shortcut that will run snip and sketch and take a new snip, a windows shortcut that will run snip and sketch and take a new snip in 3 seconds, and / or a windows shortcut that will run snip and sketch and take a new snip in 10 seconds?  Do you want to know how to do both, create a jump list and a shortcut?

Comment: @somebadhat I'm assuming that those Jump lists are merely arguments passed to to the command line.
For instance, to run `Take a new snip` you can do something like 
`ScreenSketch.exe -new`
If I'm true, I need to know how to create a shortcut to do that, if I'm wrong, you can tell me how exactly this list works under the hood and I can take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked to launch the app, but I don't know the commandline for the specific jump list item.
To launch the app use

```
ms-screensketch://
```

I found 2 new ways, not clean but it works:

1. `ms-screensketch:edit` than hit `enter`
2. pin to taskbar pos 1 `Win + Alt + 1` navigate to task and press `enter` (works with any position on the taskbar from 1-10)

For snip you have to create a command line like this: `ms-screensketch://new`

I found them for 'YourPhone' by just trying:
`ms-phone://Settings` -> launches the settings page
`ms-phone://Photos` -> launches the photos page

I'm sure there is a command for a new snip, but I don't know it.

Comment: the main question is "how to add items" to the context menu, not really about how to start apps performing certain actions